# Is it possible to load, then select a child node if the parent node is unknown to the tree?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I am using jsTree as a navigator for the user to select different items which display in another pane. So far everything is working as expected except if the user (from the other pane) selects an item that hasn't been loaded into the tree yet.

The Tree is currently getting all of its data from AJAX.

I have tried using the `open_node()` and `load_node()` functions but they have no effect if the parent node is not loaded.

My question: is it possible to load, then select a child node if the parent node is unknown to the tree? If not, are there any workarounds to achieve a similar effect?

EDIT:

Tree initializer:

```
    $('#jsTree-Location').jstree({
    "core": {
        "animation": 0,
        "check_callback": true,
        "themes": {
            "stripes": true,
            "icons": true
        },
        "data": {
            'url': '@Url.Action("LocationList", "Location")',
            'type': 'GET',
            'dataType': 'JSON',
            'contentType': 'application/json',
            'data': function (node) {
                return { sID: node.id, sType: node.type };
            }
        }
    },
    "json_data": {},
    "plugins": [
        "contextmenu", "dnd", "search",
        "state", "wholerow", "types"
    ],
    "state": { "key": "system" },
    "contextmenu": { items: customMenu },
    "types": {
        "default": {
            "icon": "glyphicon glyphicon-flash"
        },
        "location": {
            "icon": "fas fa-map-marker-alt"
        },
        "asset": {
            "icon": "fa fa-cube"
        },
        "link": {
            "icon": "fa fa-cube"
        },
        "system": {
            "icon": "fas fa-cogs"
        }
    }
}})
```

Function called when user 'externally' selects a node

```
    function DisplayAsset(id) {
    ShowSpinner($("#window"), "Loading Asset...");

    //If Location Tree is active, activate the Asset in it.
    var sysTree = $('#jsTree-Location').jstree().get_selected()[0]
    if (typeof sysTree !== "undefined") {
        $("#jsTree-Location").jstree().open_node(['#asset-' + id, '#link-' + id], function (node, status) {
            if (status) {
                $("#jsTree-Location").jstree().activate_node(node)
            }
        })

    }

    //AJAX call to get Asset partial display
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Assets/_AssetEdit/',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {
            'id': id
        },
        success: function (html) {
            HideSpinner($("#window"));
            $("#window").html(html)
            BuildTable();
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: I could use some clarification as to what the specific desired outcome and the actual undesired outcome are. The way I read this question currently is something like: "Can this jQuery plugin traverse data structures that don't exist?" And the answer to that question is no. It is entirely possible you mean to ask a different question, please elaborate or clarify if you can so do.

Comment: `if (status) {$("#jsTree-Location").jstree().activate_node(node)}`
Looks to me like this code might be unreachable, I don't see any line where `status` may be passed into the `if` statement of the `DisplayAsset` function. Best of luck!